# Get weekday id in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want get day id from my datetime field.

print(datetime.today().weekday())    -->   return 4

```
my_datetime = self.start
```

print(my_datetime)  return 2017-07-14 09:47:14

How replace datetime.today with my my_datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example, return day name:

```
my_datetime = self.start
day_name = datetime.strptime(my_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(day_name.strftime("%A"))
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't like that solution, because you use a datetime format/pattern out of nowhere. Either you get it from Odoo by `from odoo.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT` or use Odoo's built-in convert methods, like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Odoo's built-in convert methods to do that:

```py
from odoo import fields  # usually already done for odoo models

if self.start:
    day = fields.Datetime.from_string(self.start).weekday()
```